# How to run Docker container with .NET Core app at productiuon machine?

Tags: docker, .net-core

It's a newbie question.

Given a sample .NET Core application. Using tutorials, I've built a docker image and I can run it via `docker run` at my local machine (Win10). Docker uses Linux containers.

Now I want to obtain this image somehow at my testing machine (Ubuntu-18.04, docker is installed).

How to do this?
Can docker image be redistributed as a file, using simple copying?
Unfortunately, all reading I've found ends up with running image locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For production machines with limited access to internet, I [docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) the built image, copy, and [docker load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) it elsewhere. This is painful but unavoidable sometimes.

You can also use docker [registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/). GitLab provides their own registry which can be integrated in your work flow. Regardless of the provider, this allows you to `docker pull` the image from other machines

---